# setValue() not working in firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create new data in the firebase realtime database
I tried to use a HashMap and an object, none of them works.
even when I put the OnComplete/OnSuccess/OnFailure listeners I don't receive any data in the log.

```
private void registerUser(final String displayName, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String uid = currentUser.getUid();
                            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                            User user = new User(displayName, "Bonjour!", "par defaut", "def");
                            userMap.put("name", displayName);
                            userMap.put("status", "Bonjour!_Je_viens_de_m'inscirire");
                            userMap.put("image", "par_defaut");
                            userMap.put("thumb_image", "def");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + userMap);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + user);
                            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid);
                            mDatabaseReference.setValue(user)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    });
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + mDatabaseReference);
mRegProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Intent maintIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            maintIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(maintIntent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                            mRegProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "impossible d'inscrire, veuillez ressayer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```

I tried adding this code and it gives me :" not connected " in the log.

```
//check if connected
                            DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
                            connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                                    if (connected) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "connected");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
                                }
                            });
```

the HashMap contains the actual data but the setValue() method does not work for some reason. When I look in the firebase console there are no changes.

Comment: The completion listener only fires once the data is written/rejected on the servers. Does your device have a connection to the internet/Firebase servers?

Comment: What happens if `!task.isSuccessful()`? We can't see your code.  What does logcat say?

Comment: yes, it is connected to the internet and detectable in analytics.
for the unsuccessful part i have this: 
```
} else {
                            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

                            mRegProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "impossible d'inscrire, veuillez ressayer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code responsible for changing the activity from RegisterActivity to MainActivity ran before actually being able to send the data to the database.
to solve the problem I just put the part of the code responsible for changing the activity and all that:

```
mRegProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Intent maintIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            maintIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(maintIntent);
                            finish();
```

inside the OnSuccessListener.
so the final code is:

```
private void registerUser(final String displayName, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String uid = currentUser.getUid();
                            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                            userMap.put("name", displayName);
                            userMap.put("status", "Bonjour!_Je_viens_de_m'inscirire");
                            userMap.put("image", "par_defaut");
                            userMap.put("thumb_image", "def");
                            mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference("Users").child(uid);
                            mDatabaseReference.setValue(userMap)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
                                            mRegProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Intent maintIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            maintIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(maintIntent);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                            mRegProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "impossible d'inscrire, veuillez ressayer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

thanks for the commenters.